# Numpy condition with isclose function

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a column named 'daychange' with a bunch of values. Now i want to make another column that will check if a certain value in 'daychange' is met along with some variation.

Following is my attempt:

```
cond16 = (np.isclose(df.daychange = 0.03, rtol = 0.002))
 df['day3'] = np.where(cond16, 100, 0)
```

It gives out a syntax error, THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

try using `==` in the first line